# Can you use double brackets in a nested for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

What I mean by my question is that if I have a nested for loop like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n"___);
    } 
}
```

What would I put in the blank? Would [i][j] be illegal if I declared an array already?

Comment: `printf("%d\n"[i][j]);` is illegal, and that fact has nothing to do with for loops.

Comment: No, nothing wrong with that assuming the array was declared as `int arrayName[x][y];` where x and y are at least 10

Comment: @asimes: ... and assuming that he wants to write `printf("%d\n", arrayName[i][j])`, and not `printf("%d\n"[i][j])` as in immibis's comment.

Comment: @Amadan, I would hope that he didn't intend to write it as immibis suggested...

Comment: The obvious thing to do would be to just try it and see what happens. The compiler is very good at telling you if something is illegal syntax.

Comment: @AlanAu Actually, in C, it's often not.

Comment: @immibis I was specifically referring to syntax (it's not clear whether OP is asking purely about syntax or not). Are you saying there are some invalid syntax scenarios that the compiler will not pick up?

Comment: @AlanAu Even with syntax, many compilers have language extensions, and they don't tell you when you're using an extension. (Contrast with, say, Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are stuck on based on your question so I made a minimal C program with comments

I declared an `int` array who's first and second dimension are at least 10 because you iterate both `i` and `j` from 0 to 9 (inclusive). This is to avoid out of bounds problems while iterating

The array's elements are not initialized in the program. It is possible that this program will print all zeros when you run it. It is also possible that it prints other values that happened to be in memory (because the array values are not initialized)

Last I declared `i` and `j` outside the for loop just in case this was the problem you were facing

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Declare an array
    // Note that both dimensions are at least 10
    // Also note that none of the values are initialized here
    int myArray[10][10];

    // Both i and j are declared here rather than in the for loop
    // This is to avoid the following potential error:
    // error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            // Note that the values this prints are uninitialized
            printf("%d\n", myArray[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question was really unclear. But from what I understand is you have some 2-d array, and you want to print contents of array.

You must have arrary already defined as `int arr[10][10]`, then you can use,

```
printf("%d\n", arr[i][j]);
```

Comment: Correct your answer... you said declare `arr` and you are printing `a` and also without a comma